# Provide dynamic CSP header with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, shopify

I'm trying to publish a Firebase app to Shopify but they are requiring the `Content-Security-Policy` header to be set to `frame-ancestors https://<CURRENT_DOMAIN>.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com;`

AFAIK Firebase Hosting doesn't allow to specify dynamic headers, and in my case I would need to use the `shop` HTTP parameter to populate my header.

Is there a way to use a Cloud Function to act as proxy and set the correct headers? May someone provide an example?

Comment: @frez were you able to solve this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Hi Celso, I faced the same issue and ended up just making the app non-embedded. As @frez asked I guess you can make a Function that proxies all requests to the hosting endpoint and modifies headers. I'm afraid I don't have an example of something like this.